# Python: Dictionaries linked data

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1 = {"dog":"woof", "cat":"meow"}
d2 = d1
d2["dog"] = "bark"
for i in d1:
    print(i, d1[i])

dog bark
cat meow
```

What's the best way to do it so:

```
dog woof
cat meow
```

Comment: You can also use slice notation. Have to double-check (on mobile), but something like [:] used after the item you want the copy of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
d1 = {"dog":"woof", "cat":"meow"}
d2 = d1.copy() # make a copy, not a reference to the same dictionary
d2["dog"] = "bark"
for i in d1:
    print(i, d1[i])

# dog woof
# cat meow
```

Answer (score 2):

`d1` and `d2` point to the same object in the memory and therefore changing values in `d2` will affect `d1` as well.

```
d1 = {}
d2 = d1
print id(d1) == id(d2)
# out: True
```

Use the copy-method of the dictionary-class or the copy-module.

```
d2 = d1.copy()
```

```
from copy import copy
d2 = copy(d1)
```

If you have mutable objects stored in the dictionary (i.e. lists) and want to copy theese as well, you should use the deepcopy-function.

```
from copy import deepcopy
d2 = deepcopy(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Copy](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) the dictionary:

```
d2 = d1.copy() # instead of d2 = d1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, both `d1` and `d2` refer to same object. You can create copy of the original dict by :

1. using `d1.copy()`
2. using `copy.copy(d1)`
3. using `dict(d1)`
4. using `copy.deepcopy(d1)`

1,2,3 will create shallow copies and 4 will create a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a better way to do this.

```
from collections import ChainMap
d1 = {"dog":"woof", "cat":"meow"}
d2 = ChainMap({}, d1)
d2["dog"] = "bark"

for i in d1:
    print(i, d1[i])
# dog woof
# cat meow

for i in d2:
    print(i, d2[i])
# dog bark
# cat meow
```

Please read ChainMap's reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

If you're using python2, to implement the ChainMap, use this minimal code recipe: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/305268/

Comment: Interesting, why do you think this way is better than dictionaries?

Comment: Hi SCD. It is neither better nor worse than dictionaries because ChainMap is a dictionary. To be more precise, underneath the abstraction, it's a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Most of the time it's a proper choice, because the original dictionary may be any size and it does not affect you. Especially if you're changing only few entries in the data.